# Objective C Converting a char * to a float and setting to a property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties, casting

In my interface header file I have:

```
@proprty (readwrite, assign) float longitude;
```

If I assign a value to that property like this:

```
loc.longitude = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)attr->children->content] floatValue];
```

The debugger says [loc longitude] does not appear to point to a valid object.

but if I use

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)attr->children->content] floatValue]);
```

the float value is written.

What am I doing wrong, its like the value is not being assigned to the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said “The debugger says [loc longitude] does not appear to point to a valid object.”

I suspect that you are trying to use this debugger command:

```
po [loc longitude]
```

The problem is that `[loc longitude]` is indeed not an Objective-C object.  It is a `float`.  You need to use a different command to print it:

```
p (float)[loc longitude]
```

or, on a recent-enough version of Xcode/lldb, you can use the dot syntax directly:

```
p loc.longitude
```

Comment: Protip: with lldb (not gdb) you can actually use `p` anywhere you would use `po`.

Comment: Thanks guys im an idiot, I was using PO, is readwrite required in the property decleration or can I admit that?

Comment: ReadWrite it the default behavior of a property.you dont need to define read write.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `[loc longitude]` is not an *object*. This means you can't use `po` in the debugger; use `p` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys im an idiot, I was using PO, is readwrite required in the property decleration or can I admit that?